# models for hierarchal classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilevel-analysis, multi-class

Are there any classifiers that can do hierarchal classification?  For example, we may have some text and want to predict it's class in an ontology (which is a tree).  As a concrete example, let's say we have some text such as "iphone 7 case" and we want to learn it maps to the path [electronics -> smart-phones & accessories -> cases] in an ontology of products. See [imagenet](http://image-net.org/explore.php?wnid=n12144987) for an example of images with hierarchal label structure).

The common naive solution is to flatten the problem into a multi-class classification problem but this simplification has two issues that a model aware of hierarchy could address:

1. If a particular class is rare or even missing in the training data than a multi-class classifier does not have enough information to make a good prediction.  A hierarchal classifier could utilize related examples that have a common ancestry with the rare class though.
2. A multi-class classifier's loss function does not give any credit if the predicted class is "almost right" (e.g. most of the path is correct but it may have predicted the child, a parent, or a sibling instead of the correct class).  A hierarchal classifier's loss function could give partial credit if the path was mostly correct.

Does anyone know of any models that can do hierarchal classification?

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole literature on the subject. The function `hclust` in R has a wide array of algorithms that do hierarchical clustering: [Complete Linkage Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering), and [Ward's D2 minimiazation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%27s_method), [Unweighted Pair Group Method with Arithmetic Mean (UPGMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPGMA), McQuitty's *weighted* PGMA, Weighted Pair Group Median Cluster (WPGMC) and Unweighted Pair Group Centroid Clustering (UPGMC, not sure why the M is there). These are discussed in Murtagh's 1985 text "Multidimensional Clustering Algorithms", a more modern reference is Legendre/Legendre's "Numerical Ecology". Freely available lecture notes are available [here](http://ubio.bioinfo.cnio.es/Cursos/CEU_MDA07_practicals/Further%20reading/Multivariate%20analysis%20Borcard%202006/Chap_3.pdf).Your concerns are inline with the overall rational for hierarchical clustering.

Your last question is for *models* that do hierarchical clustering. I am not sure which of the above *algorithms* are actually a *model*-based approach.

Comment: I am not sure how hierarchal clustering would be useful for classification since an ontology tree already defines the hierarchal structure (so there is no hierarchal structure to learn).

Comment: @anthonybell Perhaps I misunderstood the question. Are you saying you have a known hierarchy and you wish to classify observations according to it?

Comment: yes the target of classification is a node in a tree that's already defined (such as wordnet, imagenet, taxonomy)

Comment: @anthonybell that doesn't make sense. How do you classify a node? It is a structure you've already set. What are your data? What are you observing and how does it relate to this "tree"?

Comment: The input is text/image and the output is a node in a tree (see [imagenet](http://image-net.org/explore.php?wnid=n00451370) as an example).

Comment: @anthonybell I daresay you're overthinking this. I don't know what Imagenet does. You can write the author(s), ask their methods, and post an answer, I'd like to know. If *I* were handling this problem, I'd do a hierarchical cluster. The images have a set of features, such as the presence or absence of a number of objects, and the weights showing the degree of alignments of various types of fitting characteristics, and these weights are inputs to a hierarchical cluster. The map is self-organizing. If there are too few features to distinguish people and dogs, its one category.

Comment: An example of this is fasttext's use of hierarchal softmax:  the targets form a binary tree and each node has a linear model to decide which child a datum would go to (left or right).  So a new example $x$ would calculate dot($x$,$w_{root}$) and go left if negative and right if positive and  continue until a leaf is reached.  ([this paper](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lisa/pointeurs/hierarchical-nnlm-aistats05.pdf) in section 5 shows an example of this using wordnet).